# Nested route using getComponent does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been building a React app with a `react-router` 3.x setup like this:

```jsx
<Route component={Global}>
    <Route path="/" getComponent={(loc, cb) => loadRoute('Home', cb)} />
    <Route path="/app" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute
            getComponent={(loc, cb) => loadRoute('AppHome', cb)}
        />
        <Route
            path="search"
            getComponent={(loc, cb) => loadRoute('Search', cb)}
        />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

I've had this working really well for chunking the containers within `App`. The `loadRoute` function wraps a `System.import` call adding `containers/${name}/index.js`.

However, adding a dynamic `getComponent={loadRoute(...)}` to `App` and navigating to `/app` causes `Global` to have no children; the JS chunks for `App` and `AppHome` are downloaded but nothing is mounted.

The `loadRoute` function:

```
const loadRoute = (container, callback) => {
    return System
        .import(`containers/${container}/index.js`)
        .then(module => callback(null, module.default))
        .catch(errorLoading);
};
```

Comment: For curiousity sake why not just use component={Component}? What gains do you get via getComponent

Comment: @KornholioBeavis it means that users don't have to load the entire application in one JS file, it gets split up into multiple files this way.

Comment: Since `System.import` is a promise - you should load component first and `.then` - `renderRoute`, check implementation here https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/routes.js

Comment: @elmeister I have added my loadRoute function to the question, it uses `.then`.

Comment: So is it because the promises aren't linked together like on line 24 of that file in `react-boilerplate`?

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1056

Comment: @elmeister sorry, I don't think that helps. The solution they end up with looks like the code I have above: an `IndexRoute` with a `getComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody seeing this question and being in the same position. I solved this a few months ago.

I used `component` instead of `getComponent` and passed it a component that is in charge of asynchronously loading the chunk, displaying a loading spinner and rendering it when available. The [react-async-component](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-async-component) package would also solve this issue.

Now, chunked routes can be nested many levels deep allowing for true code splitting in `react-router` 3.x.

**components/AsyncComponent.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

const defaultLoadingElement = <div>Loading spinner...</div>;

const asyncComp = (getComponent, loadingElement = defaultLoadingElement) => {
  return class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    static Component = null;
    state = { Component: AsyncComponent.Component };

    componentWillMount() {
      if(!this.state.Component) {
        getComponent().then(Component => {
          AsyncComponent.Component = Component;
          this.setState({ Component });
        });
      }
    }

    render() {
      const { Component } = this.state;
      if(Component) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }

      return loadingElement;
    }
  };
};

export default asyncComp;
```

**routes.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router';

import asyncComp from 'components/AsyncComponent';

const loadRoute = container => asyncComp(() =>
  import(`containers/${container}/index.js`)
    .then(module => module.default)
);

const errorLoading = err => {
  const error = new Error();
  console.log(error.stack, err.stack);
  throw new Error(`Dynamic page loading failed: ${err}`);
};

export default store => {
  return (
    <Route path="/admin" component={loadRoute('Admin')}>
      <IndexRoute component={loadRoute('Admin/Dashboard')} />
      <Route
        path="accounts"
        component={loadRoute('Admin/Accounts')}
      />
    </Route>
  );
};
```